# How can I search inside large number of Log Files for specific keywords in Python?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, search, logging

So, I am in the situation where I have to search for a specific keyword inside a directory containing large number of log files to return the whole line containing that keyword. I basically want to make a local search engine for searching inside the log files.
I can proceed by reading each and every file by and searching inside of it for each files line by line, but that would be highly inefficient (obviously). 
How can I proceed with this situation considering I have more than 30 thousand files each having approx 600 lines and of size approx 150kB? I am working on a project based on django/python.

Comment: You can look into [ELK Stack](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack)

Comment: Can ELK Stack index the contents of file as well, as I have to search inside each file for the keyword?

Comment: Not sure on that. But for larger logs parsing, its best to use ELK setup. You can check this tutorial on how to set it up with django: https://www.codementor.io/samueljames/using-django-with-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-9l4fwx138.